# NodeJs - How do I return response with a list of msg after the for loop is completed

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, promise

I am using nodejs.

How do i ensure that my for-loop completely finished running, so that i can return my msgList which is populated with records of which one pass/fail?

Is there a proper way if using callback or promise for this case?

Right now what i am getting is :

**Result:**

```
{
    "message": "Handling PUT requests to /api/micontact.",
    "result": []
}
```

**Code:**

```
exports.updateBooks = (req, res) => {       

    var books = req.body.books;

    var createdBy = constant.defaultUsername;
    var currentDate = converter.formatDate(new Date());

    let msgList = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {

        let msgArr = "Record index: " + i + " ";

        var params = [];

        var book = books[i];

        var bookId = globUtil.checkforUndefined(book.bookId);
        var title = globUtil.checkforUndefined(book.title);

        if(bookId === null) {
            msgArr += message.bookId ;
            msgList.push(msgArr)
        }


        params.push(title, bookId);

        pool.open(connString, function (err, db) {
            if (err) {

                msgArr += err;
                msgList.push(msgArr);

                return;
            }

            db.query(query.sqlUpdate, params, function (error, result, info) {

                if (error) {

                    msgArr += error;
                    msgList.push(msgArr);

                    return;
                }

                msgArr += "SUCCESS";
                msgList.push(msgArr);
            });

            db.close();
        });
    }

    res.status(200).json({
        message: format(message.defaultMsg, "PUT", constant.moduleUrl),
        result: msgList 
    });
};
```

Comment: If you are using 'Promise's, what methods in your code return a 'Promise' ? Mention it .

Comment: @ZeekHuge not using promise yet. As i am still rading up on how to use it to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use promise following way, make appropriate changes for your code. More about promise [link](https://www.promisejs.org/)

```
var fetchData = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        pool.open(connString, function (err, db) {
                if (err) {
                   reject();
                }

            db.query(query.sqlUpdate, params, function (error, result, info) {
                if (error) {
                    reject();
                }

                resolve();
            });
            db.close();
        });
    });
};

exports.updateBooks = (req, res) => {       
...

    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        fetchData(i).then(function(result){
            count+=1;
            if(count == books.length){
                //send response
                res.status(200).json({
                 message:format(message.defaultMsg,"PUT",constant.moduleUrl),
                result: msgList 
                });
            }
        }).catch(function(err){
            //send error
        })
    }
};
```

Comment: Hmm.  I doubt that db.close() is placed correctly (not your error, but the OP probably has this wrong).  Also, you should pass params to fetchData.  Also (importantly) resolve should resolve with results, reject should be called with err.  Finally, the counter is clumsy; instead, make an array of promises in the loop, then use Promise.all() to run them all.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because NodeJS works asychronizely and communicate using callbacks, you can use the below way acheive your requirement:

```
exports.updateBooks = (req, res) => {       

    var books = req.body.books;

    var createdBy = constant.defaultUsername;
    var currentDate = converter.formatDate(new Date());

    let msgList = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {

        let msgArr = "Record index: " + i + " ";

        var params = [];

        var book = books[i];

        var bookId = globUtil.checkforUndefined(book.bookId);
        var title = globUtil.checkforUndefined(book.title);

        if(bookId === null) {
            msgArr += message.bookId ;
            msgList.push(msgArr)
        }


        params.push(title, bookId);

        pool.open(connString, function (err, db) {
            if (err) {

                msgArr += err;
                msgList.push(msgArr);

                return;
            }

            db.query(query.sqlUpdate, params, function (error, result, info) {

                if (error) {

                    msgArr += error;
                    msgList.push(msgArr);

                    return;
                }

                msgArr += "SUCCESS";
                msgList.push(msgArr);

res.status(200).json({
        message: format(message.defaultMsg, "PUT", constant.moduleUrl),
        result: msgList 
    });
            });

            db.close();
        });
    }


};
```